# How to use pass token to authorize the access to data in WPF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I have an API that has login and register functions. When user logins he gets a token which when it is authorized I want that in WPF data grid would appear a data.

```
        private async void btn_Authorize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string token = txt_Code.Text;

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7085/Picture");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var pictures = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Picture>>();
                dtg_Pictures.ItemsSource = pictures;
            }
        }
```

And this is login button

```
        private async void btn_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var user = new User()
            {
                Username = txt_Name.Text,
                Password = txt_Password.Text
            };

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:7085/api/Auth/Login", user);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var wpfServiceResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<string>>();
                if (wpfServiceResponse != null && wpfServiceResponse.Success)
                {
                    string data = wpfServiceResponse.Data!;
                    txt_Code.Text = data;
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect when I login and press "Authorize" button I would see data in my table.

Comment: Before anything else **DO NOT** create new HttpClient instances per method, you are going to burn out your connection pool. One and only one `static readonly` HttpClient in the class. [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines) and see [usage here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Have you verified that "pictures" contains data in the correct format for display in your table? Could you share your xaml as well for the DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to implement token-based authorization in WPF:

```
private HttpClient httpClient;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // Initialize the HttpClient with the base URL
    httpClient = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7085/")
    };
}

private async void btn_Authorize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string token = GetStoredToken(); // Retrieve the token from storage
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("Picture");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var pictures = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Picture>>();
            dtg_Pictures.ItemsSource = pictures;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle case when token is not available or expired
    }
}

private async void btn_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        Username = txt_Name.Text,
        Password = txt_Password.Text
    };

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Auth/Login", user);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var wpfServiceResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<string>>();
        if (wpfServiceResponse != null && wpfServiceResponse.Success)
        {
            string token = wpfServiceResponse.Data!;
            StoreToken(token); // Store the token securely
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle login failure
    }
}

private string GetStoredToken()
{
    // Retrieve the token from your storage mechanism
    // Return the token or an empty string if not available
}

private void StoreToken(string token)
{
    // Store the token securely in your storage mechanism
}
```

I hope this helps!